# Баг с сортировкой участников по репутации за неделю

Tags: дефект, страница-участников

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На данный момент(когда я пишу этот пост) держится уже минут 10.

Comment: Скорее всего кэш :( У меня сейчас отображаются в правильном порядке

Comment: а у меня нет. Свой кэш почистил - пришлось даже залогиниться

Comment: Починилось......

Comment: @PashaPash, ну кэшироваться-то тоже должен правильный порядок, не?

Comment: Хм.. У нас неделя считается с ВС что ли?

Comment: @Qwertiy пора писать на MSE )

Comment: Но вообще да, это косяк кеша. Он на всех сайтах сети есть.

Comment: Должен отметить, что в момент поступления 10 баллов, которые позволили обогнать @Qwertiy, я был на этой странице.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/274245/260198

> Сортировка может занять больше времени, чем просто обновление репутации.
>
> Если пользователь получил немного репутации, то для обновления отображения оной сайту нужно обновить пару переменных (утрированно).
>
> Для обновления порядка в списке нужно затратить больше ресурсов, ведь тут задействовано множество пользователей сразу. На SO более 4 миллионов пользователей. Пересчитывать порядок при каждом изменении репутации каждого пользователя - весьма затратно.

**TL;DR:** проблема в кеше.